# How to display unicode char in kdb console

Tags: kdb

I am following the example here: https://code.kx.com/q/kb/unicode/, and it all works as expected, but it is still very inconveinent to work with unicode in a table:

```
q)select from t
sym     name text                                                            ..
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------..
apples  蘋果 "\303\277\310\325\322\273\314O\271\373, \341t\311\372\337h\353x\..
bananas 香蕉 "\317\343\275\266\264\254\312\307\322\273\265\300\277\311\277\33..
oranges 橙   "\217\304\267\360\301_\300\357\337_\326\335\201\355\265\304\365r..
```

Is there a way to display the unicode char properly in kdb console? I know we could use symbol, but I believe symbol types requires different storage, and may not appropriate for free text, so would like to see a way for char types to work.

Or are there any other tool that could enable us to work with unicode smoothly? - I've tried qStudio, unicode seems like not supported at all, even for symbol types

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Studio for kdb+](https://github.com/CharlesSkelton/studio) displays tables with unicode characters properly, so does any JetBrains' [IDE](https://www.jetbrains.com/products.html#type=ide) with [KDB+ Studio plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10894-kdb-studio) installed (the plugin is based on Studio's code). Both are cross-platform.

[image]

If you are on Windows, try [QInsightPad 2.1](http://www.qinsightpad.com), it should handle Unicode properly too.